# primefaces dashboard senderColumnIndex is null

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I use PF v. 5.3.5 and JSF v. 2.2.8.

```
public void changedSort(DashboardReorderEvent event) {
    int oldIdx = event.getSenderColumnIndex();
    int idx = event.getItemIndex();    //this works correctly
}
```

and my dashboard component.

```
<p:dashboard id="sortDashboard" model="#{customAttributesSettings.sortModel}" disabled="#{!customAttributesSettings.editable}">
    <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{customAttributesSettings.changedSort}" update="@form:customTabSet:sortCurrent" immediate="true"/>
    <c:forEach var="sortColumn" items="#{customAttributesSettings.availableSortColumns}">
        <p:panel id="#{sortColumn.id}" header="#{sortColumn.name}">
            <!--some components-->
        </p:panel>
    </c:forEach>
</p:dashboard>
```

How shall I fix or work round it, please?

Comment: I solved by a very complicated work round. So, I think that it is not suitable to post it here.